# SUM values with VLOOK

Tags: excel, sum, vlookup

I have an Excel sheet with monthly costs per food. The goal is, on a part sheet, to calculate the value of each food in every month. With a formula I am using at the moment `=SUM(VLOOKUP (A3; Food! C3: K3000; 7; 0))`, it is only looking for a relative value in the first month and not in the total of all months.

To clarify the formula:

1. `A3` is the food I'm looking for;
2. `Food! C3: K3000` is the range of the table where I am looking for the data;
3. Finally, 7 will be the column index where the amount spent per month is.

This is what I have in Food sheet:

[image]

I think there is no extra information. If something else is left, please tell me.

That's the result I want:

[image]

Comment: VLOOKUP returns a single value.

Comment: Without clear info, have you tried SUMIFS() which takes multiple criteria?

Comment: What they said,  besides, it sounds like a simple job for a Pivot Table.

Comment: Can you post a real example of your input and expected output? This question needs more focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUMIF`:

```
=SUMIF($B$3:$B$11;G3;$C$3:$C$11)
```

[image]

Comment: Just a clarification. `B3:B11` and `C3:C11` should be with absolute references. Right now the formula works because data sorting on both datasets is the same. But if it changes, the formula will return a wrong result. So it should be `=SUMIF($B$3:$B$11;G3;$C$3:$C$11)`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I didn't notice it in a hurry. Corrected.